# Swift Facebook integration login callback issues

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm trying to integrate `Facebook login` for my `swift3` application.

I'm reading this documentation [Facebook SDK for Swift](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift).

After the installation with `pod`

```
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

And add them in `Linked framework and libraries`, the facebook login is working as in the example displaying a safari window to login with facebook and redirecting the the same ViewController.

But, I have two specific questions.
The first one, I need add a callback after the facebook login redirection (successful or error) and assign the current token.

My current code is:

```
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
        var fbtoken = AccessToken.current

        LoginManager().logOut()

        if(fbtoken != nil){
            let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
            connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me")) { httpResponse, result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
                }
            }
            connection.start()
        }

        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])

        let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 10
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newCenterY)
        loginButton.center = newCenter

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
}
```

The `fbtoken` variable is always `nil` and reading [Login Behavior documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/reference/enums/loginbehavior.html) is not working to assign a `callback`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following could cause the access token to be nil

1. You didn't set `info.plist` appropriately: you must have a boolean value set to `YES` with the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` under the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary
2. Facebook SDK isn't initialized properly in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your AppDelegate file: you must make this call:

   ```
   FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
   ```
3. The SDK version you have isn't up to date. Some versions reportedly had bugs in that area so updating the SDK might fix your problem if the previous 2 points are covered for you

To answer your other question, Facebook SDK has a `login` method with a closure parameter as follows

```
let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()

manager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self, handler: { (result, error) in
      if error != nil {
         // handle error
      }

      // login successful

})
```

Note: the code I provided uses `pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'` and `pod 'FBSDKShareKit'`, so there may be minor syntactical differences, but ultimately they work the same way.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you're using Facebook's `LoginButton`. In this case, refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/4.15/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate/) page of the documentation for more info. Mainly, here's what you can do:

Make sure you conform to `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` and implement the `didCompleteWithResult` method, which contains the result of the login operation. The page I linked contains the method's parameters and other details you may need.